# How to remove second caption here?

Tags: tables, captions

I have a table spread over multiple pages using tabularx:

```
\documentclass[11pt,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
BCOR=10mm,
ngerman,
english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
    \caption[Hardware and Software]{List of hardware and software used during generating and analyzing data for this thesis.}\\

    \toprule
    \textbf{Hardware} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Manufacturer}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
    \endhead

    Gelelektrophoresis power supply & peqPOWER 250V & PEQLAB Biotechnologie GmbH, Erlangen, Germany\\
    \midrule
    DNA amplifier & T Professional Thermocycler & Biometra GmbH, Jena, Germany\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & T Personal Thermocycler & Biometra GmbH, Jena, Germany\\
    \midrule
    Centrifuge & Multifuge Heraeus X1R & Thermo Scientific, Rockford, USA\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & 2k15 &SIGMA Laboratory Centrifuges GmbH, Osterode, Germany\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & xxx &xxx\\
    \midrule
    Gelelektrophoresis power supply & peqPOWER 250V & PEQLAB Biotechnologie GmbH, Erlangen, Germany\\
    \midrule
    DNA amplifier & T Professional Thermocycler & Biometra GmbH, Jena, Germany\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & T Personal Thermocycler & Biometra GmbH, Jena, Germany\\
    \midrule
    Centrifuge & Multifuge Heraeus X1R & Thermo Scientific, Rockford, USA\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & 2k15 &SIGMA Laboratory Centrifuges GmbH, Osterode, Germany\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & xxx &xxx\\
    \midrule
    Gelelektrophoresis power supply & peqPOWER 250V & PEQLAB Biotechnologie GmbH, Erlangen, Germany\\
    \midrule
    DNA amplifier & T Professional Thermocycler & Biometra GmbH, Jena, Germany\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & T Personal Thermocycler & Biometra GmbH, Jena, Germany\\
    \midrule
    Centrifuge & Multifuge Heraeus X1R & Thermo Scientific, Rockford, USA\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & 2k15 &SIGMA Laboratory Centrifuges GmbH, Osterode, Germany\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & xxx &xxx\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This works fine but I'd like to remove the caption above the table on the second page... Does anyone know, how to do this?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: If a table spans multiple pages, I think `longtable` fits better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define separately table head for the first pagee:

```
    \toprule
    \textbf{Hardware} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Manufacturer}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
\endfirsthead   % <--- on the fist page
    \toprule
    \textbf{Hardware} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Manufacturer}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
\endhead        % <--- on the other pages
```

Comment: works fine! Thank you